# Firing a Bullet to off-screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that follows the mouse, and I was wondering if, and how, I could fire a 'bullet' and have it disappear when its off screen. Here is my following code:

```
var box=$(".box");
var boxCenter=[box.offset().left+box.width()/2, box.offset().top+box.height()/2];
$(document).mousemove(function(e){    

var angle = Math.atan2(e.pageX- boxCenter[0],- (e.pageY- boxCenter[1]) )*(180/Math.PI);     

box.css({ "-webkit-transform": 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});    
box.css({ '-moz-transform': 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
box.css({ 'transform': 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/znx23hhc/) and the demo below. It fires a bullet at every click, but fire angle is not correctly working yet.

There is also the bullet handling in every bullet update interval it will check if the bullet is outside of the screen.
Every bullet is added to an array to keep track of each. Each bullet in the array has the properties - DOM element, a speed and an angle.

The game loop (setIntervall callback) is very basic and should be improved. There are many tutorials about it. e.g. check this [page](http://nokarma.org/2011/02/02/javascript-game-development-the-game-loop/).

```js
$(function () {
    var box = $(".box"),
        screenWidth = $( window ).width(),
        screenHeight = $( window ).height(),
        $bullet = $('<div/>').addClass('bullet'),
        bulletSpeed=10,
        bulletList = [],
        angle = 0,
        boxCenter = [box.offset().left + box.width() / 2, box.offset().top + box.height() / 2];

    console.log(screenWidth, screenHeight);    
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {

        angle = Math.atan2(e.pageX - boxCenter[0], -(e.pageY - boxCenter[1])) * (180 / Math.PI);
        //console.log(angle);
        box.css({
            "-webkit-transform": 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
        });
        box.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
        });
        box.css({
            'transform': 'translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
        });

    });
    $(document).on('click', function() {
        console.log('fire bullet');
        var $newBullet = $bullet.clone();
        $(document.body).append($newBullet);
        bulletList.push({$el: $newBullet, 
                         speed: bulletSpeed, 
                         angle: parseInt(angle)});
    });
    
    var checkBullet = function() {
        if (bulletList.length > 0) {
            $.each(bulletList, function(index, bullet) {
                if ( !bullet ) return;
                
                // tan = top/left = sin/cos
                var y = bullet.$el.position().top;
                var x = bullet.$el.position().left;
                x += Math.cos( (90-bullet.angle) * Math.PI / 180) * bullet.speed; // spped angle not correct yet.
                y += Math.sin( bullet.angle * Math.PI / 180) * bullet.speed; // speed angle not correct!
                bullet.$el.css({left: x, top: y});
                //console.log(x);
                if ( x > screenWidth || y > screenHeight ){
                    // off-screen --> delete bullet
                    bullet.$el.remove();
                    delete bulletList[index];
                    console.log('bullet '+ index +' destroyed!');
                }
            });
        }
    };
    
    setInterval(checkBullet, 1/30);
});
```

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.bullet {
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: If you can fix this, that would be amazing!

Comment: I googled a bit and found a similar demo. Please have a look at this [page under mechanics/aiming](http://examples.kiwijs.org/) and at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/ahjbh3rs/).  The fiddle based on kiwijs is working better than my demo also the fire angle is working there.